# Homomorphism Transitivity

Tags: group-theory

Show that $G\times H\cong H \times G$ and that if $A\cong G$
and $B\cong H$, then $A\times B\cong G\times H$.

So you make a isomorphism $\phi$ from $G \times H \mapsto H \times G$ and because this is a isomorphism there is an inverse $\phi^{-1}$ such that  $G \times H \mapsto H \times G$ Then I make two more homomorphisms from $A \mapsto G$ and $B \mapsto H$ But then do I need to define another homomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

> Show that $G\times H\cong H \times G$ and that if $A\cong G$
>   and $B\cong H$, then $A\times B\cong G\times H$.
>
> So you make a isomorphism $\phi$ from $G \times H \mapsto H \times G$ and because this is a isomorphism there is an inverse $\phi^{-1}$ such that  $G \times H \mapsto H \times G$

I just want to make sure you understand that you're not given the isomorphism, but need to construct a map $\phi: G \times H \to H \times G$ and show that it's an isomorphism (an invertible homomorphism, so the biggest task is showing that $\phi$ respects multiplication; the bijection/invertible part is easier, in my opinion).

> Then I make two more homomorphisms from $A \mapsto G$ and $B \mapsto H$ But then do I need to define another homomorphism?

Knowing that $A \cong G$ and $B \cong H$, you automatically know that a pair of isomorphisms exist, say, $\phi: A \to G$ and $\theta: B \to H$.

Your job is to Frankenstein them together into a map $??: A \times B \to G \times H$. Then you'll need to justify the fact that your new map is indeed an isomoprhism.

Comment: good catch!Define $\phi(g,h) = (h,g)$ for any $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ Clearly $\phi$ maps $G \times H$ into $H \times G$ It maps onto $H \times G$ since if given $h \in H$ and $g \in G$ then $\phi(g,h) = (h,g)$ it is one to one since if $\phi(g,h) = \phi(g',h')$ Then $(h,g) =(g,h)$ therefore $h=h'$ and $g=g'$ Hence $(g,h)=(g',h')$ It is a homomorphism because $$\phi((g,h)(g',h'))=\phi(gg',hh')=(hh',gg')=(h,g)(h'g')=\phi(g,h)\phi(g',h')$$ Is this right?

Comment: @AllAboutGroups That looks good! I definitely agree with the homomorphism part, just watch the "one to one" part of the proof, don't forget your apostrophes in $(h, g) = (g, h)$. In fact, it's probably a lot less clunky to just construct the inverse of $\phi$ (which is $\phi$ itself, curiously) to verify that you have a bijection!

Comment: technically I do not know that proposition.

Comment: @AllAboutGroups Gotcha, in that case, what you have is the way to go. Just be more careful with the statement that $(h, g) = (g, h)$, I believe you want $(h, g) = (h', g')$ instead.